# Getting the spread operater syntax error during the deployment to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm getting the following error when I'm deploying my app to Heroku:

```sh
remote: SyntaxError: src/resolvers/Mutation.js: Unexpected token (21:16)
remote:   19 |         const user = await prisma.mutation.createUser({
remote:   20 |             data: {
remote: > 21 |                 ...data,
remote:      |                 ^
remote:   22 |                 password,
remote:   23 |                 permissions,
remote:   24 |                 authentication
```

During the Heroku postbuild phase, the rest spread is not being recognized.

I'm currently have the following in `index.js`:

```js
import '@babel/polyfill'
```

My `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cross-fetch": "^2.2.2",
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^4.2.3",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-cli": "^2.16.4",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.14.10",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
    "prisma-binding": "^2.1.1",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
```

I tried for `_babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        "es2015",
        "stage-3",
        "env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread", { "loose": true, "useBuiltIns": true }],
        "transform-es2015-destructuring"
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-destructuring", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

But non works. Not sure how to get around this issue.
...................

Comment: Is `_babelrc` a typo in the question, or is that really the filename you're using?  I am not aware of that being a recognized config file for babel-- I only know of `.babelrc`, `.babelrc.js` and I _think_ it can also be configured in `package.json`.

Comment: Can you show script of `package.json`

Comment: @AlexanderNied wow you're right. If you want to leave it in the reply, I'll credit you

Comment: Sure thing, thanks, glad that resolved your issue :)

Comment: Looks like you are mixing different versions of Babel. Use all 6.x or 7.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_babelrc` is not a recognized config format file for babel-- in order to configure babel you'll need to use one of the methods listed in their [config files documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files):

- `.babelrc`
- `.babelrc.js`
- `.babelrc.cjs`
- `package.json`